# Large blue windscreen with shuttle decal

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Can someone help me identify this part, I got it in a bulk lot and want to know what sets are in there. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Windscreen 8 x 6 x 3 Wedge with Space Port Pattern on Top and Sides (Stickers) - Set 6453](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=551pb01).